# Обратный треугольник в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, циклы

Мне необходимо сделать обратный треугольник, используя цикл for вот в таком виде, параметр `n = 5`;

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

А вот мой код:

```js
function tornadoTriangle(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = n; j >= i; j--) {
      document.write('*');
    }
    document.write('<br>');
  }
}
tornadoTriangle(5);
```

Comment: Да опять? Сколько уже можно? Одними учебниками пользуетесь?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506399/207618

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/580522/207618

Comment: @Other, там другой вид треугольника, но если ты нажмешь на дубликат - я закрою

Comment: @Grundy, алгоритм-то дан.

Comment: @Other, тогда почему нет голоса за закрытие? :)

Comment: @Grundy, ожидайте, я не справляюсь с потоком, Цезарь завидует.